# If you extracted 5 volts of energy from the human body for eight hours, how many calories would that burn?

Tags: energy, voltage

I'm designing a device that is able to extract up to 5 volts from your body. I was wondering how many calories this would burn in eight hours? Suppose you went to sleep at night with this device attached to you for eight hours, and it was extracting 5 volts (constant) from your body. Does anyone know how many calories this would burn? I'm trying to see if this would be safe to use, or if I'm going to have to bump it down a couple of volts so that it doesn't take too much energy. Thanks in advance!

P.S. I've also asked this question on Biology and Medical Sciences Stack Exchange, but it's been closed on both sites for being off topic. I've been told to ask this here.

EDIT: Clearly I have a bit more research to do with this. I'll get back to you when I do some more testing with this device.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "extracting 5 volts". This would include a brief description of how you will do it.

Comment: A volt is not a unit of energy. Every appliance in your house runs on 120/240V, but a microwave uses far more energy per second than an LED lightbulb, for example. Energy can be expressed in terms of Watt-hours or Volt-Amp-seconds - you need to tell us either the power consumption of the device (100W, 1000W, etc.), or its current draw (1A, 10A, etc). The voltage alone can't tell you the energy consumption.

Comment: If you don't understand that Volts aren't a measure of energy, then I would VERY STRONGLY  advise against building ANY device involving electricity and human beings!

Comment: *I'm designing a device that is able to extract up to 5 volts from your body* How, pray tell? How will you turn a human body into essentially a battery?

Comment: @Gert, the OP is apparently attempting to construct "The Matrix".

Comment: @DavidWhite Yes, sounds like it.

Answer (score 2):

Voltage doesn't directly relate to energy or power.  A solid-state 5V battery would maintain that voltage indefinitely as long as charges do not flow in the system.

For electrical devices that can maintain a voltage even while current is flowing, the power required is the product of voltage and the current.  As your question doesn't mention current, there is no answer.  A smoke alarm "extracts" 9V from a battery inside over the course of several years, but the battery only starts with the equivalent of 5 nutritional calories (kcal).

Finally, although the human body does use electrical potentials in some cellular processes, I don't know of any mechanism that directly converts stored energy (especially in lipid form) to electrical power.  As such, the description of "able to extract 5V" is incomplete and suspect.

Comment: Amazing how someone about to 'design' yet another snake oil 'slimming device' is so candid about his own ignorance...

Comment: There are fuel cells that run on glucose. The issue in using one in the human body is all the other non-glucose stuff that is running around.

Comment: Basically, this device must operate either by physically removing fats and sugars from the body (in which case it's just liposuction), or by sending cells into metabolic overdrive to force them to consume the fats and sugars themselves. That sounds both totally infeasible and incredibly dangerous, putting this firmly in the category of Bad Ideas.

Comment: @JonCuster, good point.  I was thinking of "external" devices.  But I agree physical/chemical processes would be at least possible, if perhaps a poor fit to "voltage extraction".

Comment: @BowlOfRed - there has been quite a bit of research on them to power things like pacemakers. Another option was using a dermal patch to extract glucose, then powering external devices. I recall a conversation at work around that, which immediately led to the 'killer app' of weight loss using one such patch just connected to an external resistor to dump the heat. A sedentary human is about 100W, so if you could just get 10W additional power output your base metabolism goes up 10%. "Just"...